# Multiple Densities With Separate Weights in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

In `R` I would like to plot the kernel density of a data frame column `x` by group `y` using weights `w`.

My problem is that the weighting is done over all of the data, not by groups. This leads to the "sum of weights < 1" error.

Here is a MWE:

```
n = 10000
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n), y = rbinom(n,1,prob=0.25), w = exp(rnorm(n)))

# Make density plots by y, weighted by w
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,group=y)) + geom_density(aes(weights=w/sum(w)))
```

[image]

As you can see, neither of the densities integrate to one.

How do I get weighting to be done by group?

Comment: Perhaps, this could help [Density of each group of weighted geom_density sum to one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342494/density-of-each-group-of-weighted-geom-density-sum-to-one)

Comment: Ah! Thanks! My search terms must've been just different enough that I didn't see this.